# How to set a different Static homepage for Mobile version? (WordPress)

Tags: wordpress

I would like to have a different static homepage for my mobile version of my website. It is not really an extra mobile version but it is responsive.

I have a Fullscreen Image slider right now set as the static homepage. This scales to the screensize, due to the responsive build of the website, but it does not look very nice on a mobile device, such as an iPhone.  So I have this other homepage template which I would like to use when the website is being viewed on a mobile device.

Can this be done by any plugins or should it be done by coding? I don't want to use a theme switcher or something like that, I just want to have a different static page set for mobile devices.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 10):

You could use [`wp_is_mobile`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_is_mobile) to check for mobile, and hook into [`template_redirect`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/template_redirect) to load a different template if mobile is detected:

```
function so16165211_mobile_home_redirect(){
    if( wp_is_mobile() && is_front_page() ){
        include( get_template_directory() . '/home-mobile.php' );
        exit;
    }
}
add_action( 'template_redirect', 'so16165211_mobile_home_redirect' );
```

Comment: I might be wrong (and I hope I am as I'd like to use this too) but I understand that `wp_is_mobile` also includes tablets in the list of devices it will apply the redirect to? Have you been using this yourself and can you confirm this? +1

Comment: The code is not perfect, you might find this discussion interesting: http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/73273/wp-is-mobile-function

Answer (score 10):

I would include [Mobile-Detect](https://github.com/serbanghita/Mobile-Detect) into the theme in its own folder and add this code in the beginning of **header.php**:

```
if( is_front_page() ){

    include_once('mobile-detect/Mobile_Detect.php');
    $detect = new Mobile_Detect(); 

    if ( $detect->isMobile() || $detect->isTablet() ) {
        $redirect_url = 'http://example.com/mobile_home';
        header('Location: ' . $redirect_url ); // Redirect the user
    }
}
```

You could customize this solution to work just as you want. I have used this for several projects for similiar solutions.

Comment: I've used this on a few projects, as well - it works quite nicely, and is easily customized.

Answer (score 2):

This should work: (insert it in functions.php)

```html
    //* Redirect homepage on mobile
add_action( 'wp_head', 'wps_params', 10 );
function wps_params() {
    ?>
     <script>
 if (window.location.pathname == '/' && jQuery(window).width() <= 480) {
    window.location = "/webshop/";
 }
 </script>

    <?php
}
```

Replace "/webshop/" with your link of the mobile homepage.

Answer (score 0):

You could try to use [detectmobilebrowsers](http://detectmobilebrowsers.mobi/) script.

As I remember it is just one php file and has a single function which asks how to treat different mobile devices(iPhones, iPads, Androids, Windows Phones, BlackBerry's and Palm devices).

You can get better idea how the script works by going to this [function generator](http://detectmobilebrowsers.mobi/help/) page.

Answer (score 0):

It's easy and no need to code everything. Install "Redirection" plugin from wordpress repository.
1. Go to the settings page.
2. Enter the "Source URL" with your default desktop's homepage
3. On the "Match" option, select "URL and user agent" & on the "Action" option select "Redirect to URL". Click "Add Redirection".
4. New configuration option will be appeared. Give any title you want. The "Source URL" must be blank (means that is your base homepage). On the "User Agent" option, choose whether iPhone or Android. On the "Matched" option, set the redirection you want for the mobile homepage.

Done!

You surely can differentiate the homepage on desktop and mobile device based on the redirection you have set before with that plugin. However, you cannot have same url name (ex: www.abcde.com for desktop & www.abcde.com/mobilehomepage for mobile device).

Answer (score 0):

This is great for me:

```
function so16165211_mobile_home_redirect(){
    if( wp_is_mobile() && is_front_page() ){
        include( get_template_directory() . '/home-mobile.php' );
        exit;
    }
}
```

Comment: Maybe expand this answer with where that code should go, what it does and how to use it?

Answer (score 0):

Adding the following to your functions.php should do the trick:

```
//* Redirect homepage on mobile

add_action( 'wp_head', 'wps_params', 10 );

function wps_params() {
?>

<script>
if (window.location.pathname == '/' && jQuery(window).width() <= 480) {
   window.location = "/webshop/";
}
</script>

<?php
}
```